# Disable justification of multi-line text in a minipage

Tags: itemize, minipage, justification

I have a minipage within a table:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}[nosep,after=\strut]
        \item Very long entry that needs breaking
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

I want it to not be justified in this specific part of the document. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright`? question is not clear, missed is MWE (Minimal Working Example).

Comment: @Zarko Solved, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. Meanwhile  I wrote short, more complete answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem with either:

- `\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright`
- `\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\RaggedRright` which requires the `ragged2e` package in the preamble.

The second option enables hyphenation of (long) words when it is appropriate, but the text remains ragged on its right side.